# My HTML elements change position according to screen size

Tags: html, css

I have an issue positioning HTML elements. I know this has a pretty simple answer but I struggle with this issue on every website I make and I'm a newbie at web dev.

```
.artstation_b{
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 395%;
}
.behance_b{
    position: absolute;
    left: 49%;
    top: 394.5%;
}
.instagram_b{
    position: absolute;
    left: 53%;
    top: 395%;
}
```

I'm laying out my images like this if I don't set the position to absolute I just can't get the results I want. And I use absolute because I'm laying out images on images. If I don't do absolutely it lays them under or next to the image.

So everything I do is fine on my 1080p screen but when I use another 1080p screen that has a different screen size everything messes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use media queries to give style of your different contents according the different screen size here is some media queries type and hope you will find it useful

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Smartphones (portrait) ---------- */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Smartphones (landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 321px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Tablets, iPads (portrait and landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Tablets, iPads (portrait) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Tablets, iPads (landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 1224px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Large screens ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 1824px){
 /* styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So media queries make the positions of the elements stay on the same place for certain amounts of screen widths. Right? And wont i need to know every specific screen size of users? Im kinda confused haha sorry.

Comment: @YKerem For the first comment, you can think like that. Media queries allow us to change the style rules of our elements for different screen sizes.